# Как снизить размер webpack файла?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Всем привет. Есть проект, использующий webpack. При сборке приложения, файл main.js  имеет размер 8.94 Мб. Установил утилиту webpack-bunlde-analyzer. Данная утитита выдает размер 2.99 Мб. Размер папки ClientApp 421 Кб.

Пробовал вариант **Code splitting**, но мне нужно без этого.
Пытался так:

```
`resolve: { 
    modules: ['app', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: [ '.js', ],
    mainFields: [ 'browser', ],
    alias: { 'lodash-es': 'lodash' }
}`
```

Выдает ошибку `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "event-source-polyfill"`.

В чем может быть проблема? Могу ли как-нибудь снизить размер webpack?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ImgApp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.5",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "2.0.0-rc.9",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "aos": "2.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0",
    "vuelidate": "0.7.4",
    "vue-cropperjs": "4.0.0",
    "vue-cookie": "1.1.4",
    "masonry": "0.0.2",
    "masonry-layout": "4.2.2",
    "vue-masonry": "0.11.7",
    "vue-progressive-image": "3.2.0",
    "vue-masonry-css": "1.0.3",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "1.1.4",
    "axios-progress-bar": "1.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vuex": "3.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^14.0.3",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-image-upload": "1.0.1",
    "vue2-editor": "2.6.6",
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.4.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.15"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: { main: './App/index.js' },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        'scss': [
                            'vue-style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader'
                        ],
                        'sass': [
                            'vue-style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
            'lodash': 'lodash/core'
        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        modules: ['app', 'node_modules']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true,
        overlay: true
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    devtool: '#eval-source-map',
    plugins: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()]
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            cache: true,
            parallel: true,
            sourceMap: false,
            extractComments: 'all',
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: true,
                output: null
            }
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin()
    ])
}
```

Comment: какие пакеты используете ?Смотрите в сторону своих пакетов либо удалите какой то из них либо `code splitting`.И не надо стараться снижать размер webpack-а он тут не при чем

Comment: webpack-bundle-analyzer показывает, что размер папки с моими компонентами составляет 971.37 Кб, node_modules 1.96 Мб.

Comment: покажите ваш `package.json`

Comment: Добавил в содержание темы